# Java Web App outputs an image (.png) - I want to save it somewhere online and then access it

Tags: java, image

My java web app is currently hosted on Amazon (Elastic Beanstalk cloud).

A user clicks a "create image" button on the index jsp and my application generates an image with some math and then

```
ImageIO.write(result, "png", new File(generatedImageFilePath));
```

This worked fine writing from my localhost to my desktop. But now I need it to write to a file online.

How would one go about doing this?

I tried saving the created image to the path of an image that i uploaded to my Amazon Elastic Beanstalk web application environment but it doesn't overwrite the file. Do I need to find some special service to do this and give write capabilities to the application?

The other "possible" option is to just use the `ImageIO.write(result, "png", new File(generatedImageFilePath));` to write to a file location inside my WAR. I'm struggling to test this because

a) I'm not sure the syntax to point to something inside my own application file structure.

b) I'm not sure if the file will be accessible to the application's ImageIO.write whilst the application is running/hosted.

I tried putting a sample resultimage.png in my animelist1/Source Packages/mainClasses directory next to my classes and tried

```
String generatedImageFilePath = "resultimage.png";
(do stuff)
ImageIO.write(result, "png", new File(generatedImageFilePath));
```

but the image didn't get overwritten.

If this is impossible then I will try to hunt down a way for me to save an image to my web host (Amazon) whilst keeping it accessible to my web application (for both writing and reading). ANY ideas or pointers would be really appreciated. I am so close to finishing this now! *keeps plodding on*

I'm going to have a break then see what I can make of this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html

Comment: A proper hoster should allow the creation of files. Can you see/change the permissions of the parent dir?

Comment: No i dont think so, but it looks like Amazon splits up all their stuff into different modules/applications. This might be what I'm looking for... if you have a moment to glance over it and tell me if it sounds right that'd be great. Its hard for me to interpret (but that's what I'll be doing after my break) `http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html#customize-containers-windows-format-files` Thankyou. It sounds like you need to upload to Amazon cloud storage module and write an interface between that and your Web App. something like that?

Comment: That is quite an advertisement page there, but it doesn't actually tell me anything. Only that there's one hell of a network set up, but that I knew already.